# Go template: Can't use HTML tag inside range block

Tags: html, go, template-engine, go-fiber

I have a Go project use GoFiber and html template engine. When I give an array to range block in .html file, if between {{range .}} and {{end}} has no HTML tag, it runs. But when I add some, it seems to consider HTML tag as a field and return error.

connect.go

```
package database

var Database *gorm.DB

func Connect() error {
    var err error
    p := config.String("DB_PORT")
    port, err := strconv.ParseUint(p, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Invalid DB_PORT param")
    }

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        config.String("DB_USERNAME"),
        config.String("DB_PASSWORD"),
        config.String("DB_HOST"),
        port,
        config.String("DB_DATABASE"))

    Database, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
        PrepareStmt:            true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

main.go

```
pakage main

func main() {
    // Init App
    database.Connect()

    // Init Fiber App
    app := fiber.New()

    // Register router
    app.Get("/posts", controller.GetPost)

    // Fiber App listen port
    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

post.go

```
pakage model

type Post struct {
    Id        uint64    `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"`
    Content   string    `json:"content" gorm:"size:255"`
    AuthorId  uint64    `json:"author_id" gorm:"foreignKey:AuthorID;references:users(id)"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

postController.go

```
pakage controller

func GetPost(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var posts []model.Post
    database.Database.Find(&posts)
    return c.Render("views/feed.html", fiber.Map{
        "Posts": posts,
    })
}
```

views/feed.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    {{range .Posts}}
    <p>{{.Content}}</p>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

It returns error: `failed to execute: template: :13:5: executing "" at <.    <p>>: can't evaluate field     <p> in type model.Post`

Comment: I think you should provide complete code (but minimal!) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks, I just add complete logic for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. My code misses the engine specification (in this case is html engine). So I declare engine: `engine := html.New("./views", ".html")` and change the line initializing app

```
app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Views: engine,
    })
```